# org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device

Tags: java, smslib

I want send the sms using GSM modem, so i have used SMSlib API to send it. but i ma getting the errors like below. please help me. I am working in ubuntu 32 bit linux.

```
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage
{
public void doIt() throws Exception
{
    OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
    System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
    System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
    //SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1",   "COM4",  115200, "Huawei", "");
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, "Huawei", "E620");
    System.out.println("1");
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            System.out.println("2");
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
            System.out.println("3");
    //gateway.setSimPin("0000");
    // Explicit SMSC address set is required for some modems.
    // Below is for VODAFONE GREECE - be sure to set your own!
    gateway.setSmscNumber("+919417099997"); // +306942190000 for vodafone
    Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    System.out.println("4");
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
            System.out.println("5");
    Service.getInstance().startService();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Modem Information:");
    System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
    System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
    System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
    System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
    System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
    System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
    System.out.println();
            System.out.println("6");
    // Send a message synchronously.
    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("9986479478", "Hello from SMSLib!"); //306974000000
    System.out.println("7");
            Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
            System.out.println("8");
    System.out.println(msg);
    // Or, send out a WAP SI message.
    //OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("306974000000",  new URL("http://www.smslib.org/"), "Visit SMSLib now!");
    //Service.getInstance().sendMessage(wapMsg);
    //System.out.println(wapMsg);
    // You can also queue some asynchronous messages to see how the callbacks
    // are called...
    //msg = new OutboundMessage("309999999999", "Wrong number!");
    //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
    //msg = new OutboundMessage("308888888888", "Wrong number!");
    //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
    System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
    System.in.read();
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
{
    public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
    {
        System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
    try
    {
        app.doIt();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And the error i am getting like

```
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver$CharQueue.get(AModemDriver.java:535)
at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:338)
at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:313)
at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler.getSimStatus(ATHandler.java:145)
at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:132)
at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 50 seconds)
```

So please help me...advance thanking you all.

Answer (score 0):

SMSLib - Troubleshooting - Modem timeouts
http://smslib.org/doc/smslib/troubleshooting/